# React use state to show otherwise hide

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a state in react where:

```
{this.state.showorhide &&
    <MyComponent />
}
```

At the moment it will show if it's hidden.

How to I add a condition where it will otherwise hide if showorhide is already true?

Comment: i am not very clear. do you want to hide the <MyComponent /> call if showorhide is true?

Comment: your state `showorhide` is a boolean variable or an object? it's a very confusing name. If showorhide is true, you will show or hide your component?

Comment: It's boolean and set to false on load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showorhide: false
    };
}

render() {
    const { showorhide } = this.state;
    return (
        { showorhide ? <MyComponent /> : <HideComponent /> }
    );
}
```

Comment: I need an else state so it toggles

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ternary` operator to render with if/else like logic.

```
render() {
    const { showorhide } = this.state;
    return (
        { showorhide ? <TrueComponent /> : <FalseComponent /> }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick

```
{!this.state.showorhide && <MyComponent />}
```